# How to get call hierarchy in java

Tags: java, stack-trace, call-hierarchy

I have three classes named `FirstClass,SecondClass and ThirdClass`. Here follows the source of three classes:

FirstClass.java

```
public class FirstClass {
    public void firstMethod(){
        SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass();
        secondClass.secondMethod();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass();
        firstClass.firstMethod();
    }

}
```

SecondClass.java

```
public class SecondClass {
    public void secondMethod(){
        ThirdClass thirdClass = new ThirdClass();
        thirdClass.thirdMethod();
    }

}
```

ThirdClass.java

```
public class ThirdClass {
    public void thirdMethod(){
        System.out.println("Here i need to print where the call comes from,(call hierarchy) Is it possible?");
    }
}
```

On the final method(here it is `ThirdClass.thirdMethod()`) i need to print where the method call comes from (I mean the call hierarchy). So what i need to write in `thirdMethod()` for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this to access the stack of your current thread:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

This returns an array of `StackTraceElement` which you then can print or check or do whatever you want.

**However, be careful here:** If your method behaves differently depending on the caller of your method (e.g by analyzing the stack and reacting on it), you can create some really uncommon and unexpected behaviour for anybode using code like this.

Answer (score 6):

See the documentation for [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

In particular, `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` retrieves information about the trace, and `Thread.dumpStack()` prints the current stack trace.

There's no need for weird hacks with `Exception` or anything.

Answer (score 4):

Try this simple thing:

```
Thread.dumpStack();
```

Prints a stack trace of the current thread to the standard error stream.

For reference, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Subtle note, that it's writing to the error stream, so you can redirect it differently than the standard console output like this:

```
java FirstClass >normaloutput.log 2>yourstackdumps.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()

It returns an array of StackTraceElement which has a method getClassName()

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`